# [Twitter4R]Twitter::ForbiddenError

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, twitter-oauth

I'm new to Twitter4R and Ruby on Rails. I'm using Ruby 1.9.2, Rails 3.1 and Twitter4R v0.7.0.

I'm trying to get my friends list from Twitter.

```
twitter = Twitter::Client.new(oauth_access: { key: token, secret: token_secret})

#these lines works fine.
twitter.status(:post, "POST TEST!!!")
twitter.friend(:add, "xxxx_jp")

#this line will cause ForbiddenError
friends = twitter.my(:friends)
```

I've checked the following site for information.

http://twitter4r.rubyforge.org/rdoc/Twitter/Client.html

**Update**

I now added `config/initializers/twitter4r.rb`:

```
require 'twitter'

Twitter::Client.configure do |config|
    config.oauth_consumer_token = consumer_key
    config.oauth_consumer_secret = consumer_secret
end
```

When debugging, I see the `consumer_key` and `consumer_secret` in `Twitter::Consumer` on debug window. But methods that require authentication like `my(:friends)` do not work.

How do I avoid the `ForbiddenError`?

Answer (score 0):

That looks like the authentication in `Twitter::Client.new` didn't actually work. Here's a presentation on OAuth by Twitter4R's creator Susan Potter:

http://www.slideshare.net/mbbx6spp/twitter4r-oauth

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply.
I tried other methods like "status" or "timeline_for" which works without problem. 
But the method "my(:friends)" which I need does not work.

I get dynamically twitter token and token secret from database. So I need to find out how configure Twitter::client.

Anyway Thank you for your good advice.
I will check the site.

Comment: I still stuck in. There is no way. (-_-;)